# First title doesn't appear (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to add titles, but first "Lines" isn't displayed.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, title="Lines")
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, title="Points")

men = Myclass(m, s, t, a)

total_i = 0
i = 0
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, men.calculate, interval=1)
plt.show()
```

I tried use "ax1.title.set_text("Lines"), but it have no help.

men.calculate():

```
...
ax1.clear()
ax2.clear()
plt.scatter(men.targets[[..., 0]], men.targets[[..., 1]], s=20)
linearray = men.targets[men.route]
linearray = np.append(linearray, [linearray[0]], axis=0)
ax1.plot(linearray[[..., 0]], linearray[[..., 1]])
ax2.plot(linearray[[..., 0]], linearray[[..., 1]])
```

Comment: When I run this code both titles are displayed. Can you show us what lines you ran and a screenshot of the output?

Answer (score 0):

That works just fine. Could you show your code and output?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, title="Lines")
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, title="Points")

ax1.plot(list(range(10)), list(range(10)))
ax2.plot(list(range(10)), list(reversed(range(10))))
```

[image]

Comment: i see. Is it possible to provide this example with some test data, for make it possible to try it on our side?

Answer (score 0):

It's needed to add in animated function:

```
ax1.title.set_text("Lines")
ax2.title.set_text("Points")
```

after:

```
ax1.clear()
ax2.clear()
```